# hive add columns on partitioned table does not work

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, partition

I share my experience about adding columns on a partitioned hive table.
As you can see, despite the CASCADE function, the ALTER brakes my table :(

## add columns on partitioned table

### table description

```
CREATE TABLE test (
a                       string,      
b                       string,
c                       string
)
PARTITIONED BY (
x                       string,
y                       string, 
z                       string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
'orc.compress'='SNAPPY'
);
```

### duplicate the table

```
CREATE TABLE test_tmp...

hadoop distcp hdfs://.../test/* dfs://.../test_tmp

MSCK REPAIR TABLE test_tmp;

SELECT * FROM test_tmp
LIMIT 100
```

> check : OK (I get results)

### modify the table

```
ALTER TABLE test_tmp
ADD COLUMNS(
aa  timestamp,
bb  string,
cc  int,
dd  string
) CASCADE;

SELECT * FROM test_tmp
LIMIT 100

...
]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:19, Vertex vertex_1502459312997_187854_4_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 rows affected, exec/fetch time: 21.655/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 1 errors]
```

> check : KO (I get this error)

Comment: if anybody has an idea of the underlying problem... :-)

Comment: Had similar issue in 2015 -- vectorized reads would crash after an ALTER. Try to disable vectorization to make sure.

Comment: you caught it :) disabling the vectorization makes my query works... thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Hive 0.x or 1.x then you are probably a victim of...

> [HIVE-10598](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10598)   Vectorization borks when column is added to table.

...which is specific to ORC format, even if it's not apparent from the JIRA label.

There is a partial fix as of Hive 2.0 *(i.e. `ADD` is fixed, but `DROP` / `RENAME` / `CHANGE` are still crippled)* thanks to

> [HIVE-11981](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11981)   ORC Schema Evolution Issues (Vectorized, ACID, and
>   Non-Vectorized)

And another related fix as of Hive 2.1.1 for `CHANGE`

> [HIVE-14355](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14355)   Schema evolution for ORC in llap is broken
>   for Int to String conversion

To be continued...

Answer (score 0):

If you have an external hive table then you can try the following:

1. Alter the table to add new column

> ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD  COLUMNS

2. Drop the partitions
   why - this internally clears up any partition information in the metadata only as this is an external table

> ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION

3. Refresh hive metadata to read the partitions again.
   why - This will recover all the partitions in the directory of a table and updates the Hive metastore. This will enable the metadata to now reflect the new column in the partition metadata.

> MSCK REPAIR TABLE <table_name>